# getting the name of the file i saved from another page

Tags: java, class

i just want to ask how i can get the name of the file saved from another page

here's the code

```
DPFPVerificationResult result = 
            verificator.verify(features, ((Main)getOwner()).getTemplate());
        updateStatus(result.getFalseAcceptRate());
        if (result.isVerified())
            makeReport("The fingerprint is from" (should be the name of the file name i saved".");
        else
            makeReport("The fingerprint can't be recognized. Please re-try.");
    }
}
```

and the other page which saves the file i want

```
private void onLoad() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new TemplateFileFilter());
    if(chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());
            byte[] data = new byte[stream.available()];
            stream.read(data);
            stream.close();
            DPFPTemplate t = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory().createTemplate();
            t.deserialize(data);
            setTemplate(t);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "Fingerprint loading", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

i want to get the name of the file which is instantiated by data, which i will then convert to string and split to get the name

Comment: First, your last comment - _which i will then convert to string and split to get the name_; why? What's wrong with `File.getName()`?? As far as the main question goes, pass the `File` out of the `onLoad` method?

Comment: because i want to put the name of the file to the database